# Using wordpress color picker in post options

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I create post options and I want to implement wordpress color picker core inside it

I tried this code I got it from many tutorials and sources but unfortunately It's not working at all, It's like I never added the code.

HTML

```
<input name="mv_cr_section_color" type="text" id="mv_cr_section_color" value="#ffffff" data-default-color="#ffffff">
```

PHP

```
function Colorpicker(){ 
  wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'Colorpicker');
```

JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery('#mv_cr_section_color').wpColorPicker();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say how you're creating the Theme Options page, but the following is a working example. It's almost the same code as your sample code, but the enqueue is done directly on the custom menu page callback and jQuery is being referenced as `$` (note its declaration in `ready(function($)`):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Testing the Color Picker
 */

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'b5f_demo_menu' );

function b5f_demo_menu() 
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Test', 
        'Test', 
        'edit_pages', 
        'test-slug', 
        'b5f_callback_function'
    );
}

function b5f_callback_function() 
{
    wp_enqueue_script('wp-color-picker');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
    ?>
    <input name="mv_cr_section_color" type="text" id="mv_cr_section_color" value="#ffffff" data-default-color="#ffffff">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {   
        $('#mv_cr_section_color').wpColorPicker();
    });             
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

When using `admin_enqueue_scripts`, the callback function has one parameter `$hook_suffix`. With it, you can make sure the scripts and styles are only added in the correct screen:

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'b5f_custom_enqueue' );

function b5f_custom_enqueue( $hook_suffix )
{
    // CHECK IF CORRECT PAGE, IF NOT DO NOTHING
    # if ( 'my_hook-name' != $hook_suffix )
    #    return;

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Use this to check the hook_suffix name
        console.log('<?php echo $hook_suffix; ?>');
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: i'm not use this code in theme option , i use it in post option in Add New Post page ,is this code should work with it?

Comment: @magedali, please, add more details to your Question and explain this part: *`I create post options`*. I suppose that you're creating a Meta Box then, is this it?

Comment: Just tested with a meta box and it's exactly the same principle.

Answer (score 0):

Just include a jQuery file and stylesheet file by this script.

```
// Register Scripts &amp; Styles in Admin panel
function custom_color_picker_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'iris', admin_url( 'js/iris.min.js' ), array( 'jquery-ui-draggable', 'jquery-ui-slider', 'jquery-touch-punch' ), false, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script( 'cp-active', plugins_url('/js/cp-active.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '', true );

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', custom_color_picker_scripts);
```

Now create a new javascript file as like cp-active.js and keep it avobe defined “/js/cp-active.js” file path using bellows code.

```
jQuery('.color-picker').iris({
// or in the data-default-color attribute on the input
defaultColor: true,
// a callback to fire whenever the color changes to a valid color
change: function(event, ui){},
// a callback to fire when the input is emptied or an invalid color
clear: function() {},
// hide the color picker controls on load
hide: true,
// show a group of common colors beneath the square
palettes: true
});
```

Add a textbox to your settings page with a CSS class for the color picker, where you want to display the input text. I have use “color_code” for input $variable.

```
<input id="color_code" class="color-picker" name="color_code" type="text" value="" />
```

Please see more details on [Add jQuery Color Picker WordPress Theme or Plugin](https://www.e2softsolution.com/jquery-color-picker-wordpress/)